# mean.io on win7 x64 not generating correct public file paths

Tags: node.js, windows-7, mean.io

I have been messing around with node.js for a couple of days and after creating some samples with node.js/express/angularjs/mongodb, I tried moving up to mean.io.

After some try and error I finally managed to run the main app on localhost:3000.

Here is a screenshot of my FB
[image]

Notice that the `bower_components` has a correct url, but that the links to files in the `packages` folder have `\` as a separator. I know that this is a Windows thing since I had a similar problem with ZendFramework2(PHP)'s zip file generator (using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant);

So what am I missing here? Is there some special configuration that I should set in Windows?

I should mention that I already have done these steps twice:

- `npm cache clean`
- `bower cache clean`
- `npm update -g npm`
- `npm update -g grunt`
- `npm update -g grunt-cli`
- `npm update -g bower`
- `npm install -g grunt`
- `npm install -g grunt-cli`
- `npm install -g bower`
- `npm install`
- `npm update`

**UPDATE**

In \node_modules\meanio\lib\aggregation.js;line:205

```
  Meanio.prototype.Module.prototype.aggregateAsset = function(type, asset, options) {
    options = options || {};
    if (!options.inline && !options.absolute && !options.url) {
      asset = path.join(Meanio.modules[this.name].source, this.name, 'public/assets', type, asset);
    }
    Meanio.aggregate(type, asset, options, Meanio.Singleton.config.clean);
      };
```

`path.join` is creating the paths with `\` instead of `/` which is not a valid file path in a url. So what is the right way to fix this to work on Windows?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: @QuinnWilson https://github.com/linnovate/meanio/pull/26